# How to match two column elements separated by comma

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame called `mydf` where column `a` and `b` have elements separated by a comma. What I want to do is match the values in `a` and `b` columns removing (or disregarding) the values in parentheses `()` and get the `common` column in the `result`.

```
mydf
    a                           b                 
1   at1 (1) , 23-x (0)             at1,23-x,gt 
2   hh (2) , pp (0)             pp
3   cg (4) , gh (9) , th (7)    th,cg


result
    a                           b                 common
1   at1 (1) , 23-x (0)             at1,23-x,gt          at1,23-x
2   hh (2) , pp (0)             pp                pp    
3   cg (4) , gh (9) , th (7)    rh,cg             cg
```

---

**Data:**

```
mydf <- read.table(
  text = "a|b                 
    at1 (1) , 23-x (0)|at1,23-x,gt
    hh (2) , pp (0)|pp
    cg (4) , gh (9) , th (7)|th,cg",
  sep = "|", header = TRUE,
  colClasses = rep("character", 2)
)
```

Comment: Try to be mindful of that fact that people will be more likely to attempt to answer your question when you make it *convenient* to reproduce the problem. `dput` would have been a better choice for sharing your objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop through the columns of the dataset (`lapply(mydf, ..`), use `str_extract` to get the alphabetic characters.  Then, get the `intersect` of the corresponding `list` elements with `Map`, join the common elements with `toString`, `unlist` and assign the `vector` as a new column "common" in the dataset.

```
library(stringr)
lst <- lapply(mydf, function(x)str_extract_all(x, '\\b[a-z]+\\b'))
mydf$common <- unlist(Map(function(x,y) toString(intersect(x,y)),
                            lst[[1]], lst[[2]]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am having problem using your solution for the data I have just updated where I have both alphanumeric and symbols. I just want to omit elements within parenthesis , so I have tried to change your solution above in for `lst`. However I am still having problem getting right answer. Could you help me please?

Comment: @MAPK Try `lst <- lapply(mydf, function(x)str_extract_all(x, '(?<!\\()[[:alnum:]-]+'))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciated!